# adding parameters to search form for persistency

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

A form targets a results page:

```
<%= form_tag results_interventos_path do %>
      From: <%= date_select :intervento, :from, { order: [:day, :month, :year], default: Date.today-31, start_year: Time.now.year-1, end_year: Time.now.year, datetime_separator: "&nbsp;" } %>
      To: <%= date_select :intervento, :to, { order: [:day, :month, :year], default: Date.today-30, start_year: Time.now.year-1, end_year: Time.now.year, datetime_separator: "&nbsp;" } %>
      <%= collection_select(:intervento, :invoicestate_id,  Invoicestate.all, :id, :nome, prompt: "tutti") %>
```

the results are routing to a paginated (with `will_paginate`) page presently defined as:

```
post :results
```

Goal:  to maintain the search parameters in the URL so that any action taken from the results page can be returned to with a link defined by `:back` symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with proper routing, this is resolved:

```
get  :results
```

form should also point accordingly to the proper method

```
<%= form_tag results_interventos_path, method: :get do %>
```

otherwise a post is attempted.